# Response from snmpget displaying error message

Tags: bash, variables, response, snmp

Output from `out=$(snmpget -v2c -c $community $device ifDescr.2)` is not written to variable, but error message comes out to screen.

I need to put this error message to variable because of `if [[ "$out" == *"Error"* ]]`.
Is there another way to make it?

Comment: Please add more details in your question.

Answer (score 1):

snmpget is wrting error message to stderr instead of stdout. This is quite common on UNIX/Linux. But the command substitution operator `$()` is only catching stdout. If you want to catch the error message into your variable, you need to redirect stderr into stdout using `2>&1`:

```
out=$(snmpget -v2c -c $community $device ifDescr.2 2>&1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Already solved with getting error number to /dev/null and making if condition...but thank you for new knowledge :)